# To querying when a Public IP is created in Azure

Tags: azure-sentinel

I am trying to find what query has to write to capture when a Public IP is created.
I am looking to create an alerting rule, whenever a public IP is created. Can someone help me please?

I looked in Azure Diagnostics table and Azure activity table

Answer (score 0):

```
AzureActivity
| where OperationNameValue == "MICROSOFT.NETWORK/PUBLICIPADDRESSES/WRITE"
| where ActivityStatusValue == "Success"
| summarize arg_min(TimeGenerated, *) by CorrelationId
```

This query will give you the 1 event per creation event for public IP Addresses. Make sure you are ingesting the [activity logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log?tabs=powershell) for each subscription

kind regards

Alistair